# Increase array length while inside the loop to make it same size as other array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I know my question looks bit not understandable but here I will explain it.

I have 3 tables and here it is

[image]

and I have a php code here that the output is to create an array based on query and here it is.

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php';

    //Array Collectors
    $arr_tblsrce1 = array();
    $arr_tblsrce2 = array();
    $arr_tbldest  = array();

    //Main Query
    $rs_tbldest = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT appkey FROM tbl_destination');
    while ($rw_tbldest = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_tbldest)) {
        $arr_tbldest[] = $rw_tbldest['appkey'];
    }

    //Do the Following procedures during the loop of Main Query Array
    //for ($i=0; $i < count($arr_tbldest); $i++) { 
    foreach ($arr_tbldest as $main_appkey) {

        //Create an array from tbl_source1
        $rs_tblsrce1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM tbl_source1 WHERE appkey = '" .$main_appkey. "'");
        while ($rw_tblsrce1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_tblsrce1)) {
            $arr_tblsrce1[] =  $rw_tblsrce1['name'];
        }

        //Create an array from tbl_source2
        $rs_tblsrce2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT add1 FROM tbl_source2 WHERE appkey = '" .$main_appkey. "'");
        while ($rw_tblsrce2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_tblsrce2)) {
            $arr_tblsrce2[] = $rw_tblsrce2['add1'];
        }

        //Get count from the Queries.
        $cnt_tblsrce1 = mysqli_num_rows($rs_tblsrce1);
        $cnt_tblsrce2 = mysqli_num_rows($rs_tblsrce2);

        //Check and get who has the largest number between arrays (actually its mysql_num_rows).
        $newarr_length = max($cnt_tblsrce1,$cnt_tblsrce2);

        //Change the size of each array and put nulls on additional empty rows.
        $arr_tblsrce1 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce1,$newarr_length,'Empty');
        $arr_tblsrce2 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce2,$newarr_length,'Empty');
    }

    print_r($arr_tblsrce1);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($arr_tblsrce2);
    echo "<br>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my only problem is how can i make those arrays same length? look at the part with `max` and `array_pad`

this is the output

`Array ( [0] => Person 1 [1] => Person 1 [2] => Person 1 [3] => Person 1 [4] => Person 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => Address 1 [1] => Address 2 [2] => Empty [3] => Empty )`

TYSM

Comment: Looks fine,  what do you get in print_r()?

Comment: @Viney please see the edited post. my target here is for every loop if the 2 arrays are not the same make them same by putting `nulls`

Comment: @Viney I will do that by finding the max based on `mysqli_num_rows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**
The reason why your code doesn't work because it is replacing the value of this `$arr_tblsrce1` variable at the end of the loop. Let's say the last value according to your table is `456`.

The value of this is just **1**.

```
$rs_tblsrce1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM tbl_source1 WHERE appkey = '" .$main_appkey. "'");
```

and for the second is **0**:

```
$rs_tblsrce2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT add1 FROM tbl_source2 WHERE appkey = '" .$main_appkey. "'");
```

**Solution:**
In your code replace this

```
//Get count from the Queries.
$cnt_tblsrce1 = mysqli_num_rows($rs_tblsrce1);
$cnt_tblsrce2 = mysqli_num_rows($rs_tblsrce2);
```

with this

```
//Get count from the Queries.
$cnt_tblsrce1 = count($arr_tblsrce1);
$cnt_tblsrce2 = count($arr_tblsrce2);
```

and put this code outside of foreach loop

```
//Get count from the Queries.
$cnt_tblsrce1 = count($arr_tblsrce1);
$cnt_tblsrce2 = count($arr_tblsrce2);

//Check and get who has the largest number between arrays (actually its mysql_num_rows).
$newarr_length = max($cnt_tblsrce1,$cnt_tblsrce2);

//Change the size of each array and put nulls on additional empty rows.
$arr_tblsrce1 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce1,$newarr_length,'Empty');
$arr_tblsrce2 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce2,$newarr_length,'Empty');
```

Here is the whole code:

```
require 'conn.php';

//Array Collectors
$arr_tblsrce1 = array();
$arr_tblsrce2 = array();
$arr_tbldest  = array();

//Main Query
$rs_tbldest = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT appkey FROM tbl_destination');
while ($rw_tbldest = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_tbldest)) {
    $arr_tbldest[] = $rw_tbldest['appkey'];
}

//Do the Following procedures during the loop of Main Query Array
//for ($i=0; $i < count($arr_tbldest); $i++) { 
foreach ($arr_tbldest as $main_appkey) {

    //Create an array from tbl_source1
    $rs_tblsrce1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM tbl_source1 WHERE appkey = '" .$main_appkey. "'");
    while ($rw_tblsrce1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_tblsrce1)) {
        $arr_tblsrce1[] =  $rw_tblsrce1['name'];
    }
    //4


    //Create an array from tbl_source2
    $rs_tblsrce2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT add1 FROM tbl_source2 WHERE appkey = '" .$main_appkey. "'");
    while ($rw_tblsrce2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_tblsrce2)) {
        $arr_tblsrce2[] = $rw_tblsrce2['add1'];
    }
    //2

}



//Get count from the Queries.
$cnt_tblsrce1 = count($arr_tblsrce1);
$cnt_tblsrce2 = count($arr_tblsrce2);

//Check and get who has the largest number between arrays (actually its mysql_num_rows).
$newarr_length = max($cnt_tblsrce1,$cnt_tblsrce2);

//Change the size of each array and put nulls on additional empty rows.
$arr_tblsrce1 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce1,$newarr_length,'Empty');
$arr_tblsrce2 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce2,$newarr_length,'Empty');

print_r($arr_tblsrce1);
echo "<br>";
print_r($arr_tblsrce2);
echo "<br>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: do you think this `$cnt_tblsrce1 = mysqli_num_rows($arr_tblsrce1);` should be replace with this? `$cnt_tblsrce1 = count($arr_tblsrce1);` because it gives me an error but when  i change it into `count` it works

Comment: Yes you should use count instead of mysqli_num_rows. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you should try to use `FULL JOIN` query 
try like below and change it appropriately,

```
 $rs_tblsrce12 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,add1 FROM tbl_source1 t1
                              FULL JOIN tbl_source2  t2 ON t1.appkey = t2.appkey  WHERE appkey = '" .$main_appkey. "'");

        while ($rw_tblsrce1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_tblsrce12)) {
            $arr_tblsrce1[] =  $rw_tblsrce1['name'];
            $arr_tblsrce2[] = $rw_tblsrce1['add1'];

        }
```

Comment: Hi. ahmm the join will not work for me because of incorrect joining from tables so I will stick on this code. anyways tysm for effort

Comment: @NardongBagsik NP:)

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is no 1 to 1 mapping between the two arrays , to make them same length  just change a small bit here

```
    $newarr_length = max($cnt_tblsrce1,$cnt_tblsrce2); // returns bigger array 
    $newarr_length = count($newarr_length); // get the length

    //Change the size of each array and put nulls on additional empty rows.
    $arr_tblsrce1 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce1,$newarr_length,'Empty');
    $arr_tblsrce2 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce2,$newarr_length,'Empty');
```

Comment: the code `$newarr_length = count($newarr_length); ` returns 1

Comment: and the part ` $arr_tblsrce1 = array_pad($arr_tblsrce1,$newarr_length,'Empty');` does not produce the empty rows now

Answer (score 0):

Try using array fill instead of array pad

```
<?php
$a1=array_fill(3,4,"blue");
print_r($a1);
?>

$sizeoffirstsrc = sizeof($cnt_tblsrce1);
$sizeofsecondsrc = sizeof($cnt_tblsrce2);
$newarr_length = max(sizeoffirstsrc,sizeofsecondsrc);

//Change the size of each array and put nulls on additional empty rows.

$arr_tblsrce1 = array_fill($sizeoffirstsrc,$newarr_length,'Empty');
$arr_tblsrce2 = array_fill($sizeofsecondsrc,$newarr_length,'Empty');
```

Comment: how can i use that sorry. I didnt know how to use it

Comment: Edited post: read up on the documentation for array pad and array fill in w3school

Comment: I tried it but the array still doesnt have the same length

Comment: your example state `array_pad`